# Select from any of multiple values from a Postgres field

Tags: postgresql

I've got a table that resembles the following:

```
WORD    WEIGHT   WORDTYPE
a       0.3      common
the     0.3      common
gray    1.2      colors
steeple 2        object
```

I need to pull the weights for several different words out of the database at once. I could do:

```
SELECT * FROM word_weight WHERE WORD = 'a' OR WORD = 'steeple' OR WORD='the';
```

but it feels ugly and the code to generate the query is obnoxious. I'm hoping that there's a way I can do something like (pseudocode):

```
SELECT * FROM word_weight WHERE WORD = 'a','the';
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You are describing the functionality of the in clause.

`select * from word_weight where word in ('a', 'steeple', 'the');`

Comment: Thanks a mint, Mark. Were that I could have figured out how to phrase the question for Google!

Answer (score 16):

If you want to pass the whole list in a single parameter, use array datatype:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    word_weight
WHERE   word = ANY('{a,steeple,the}'); -- or ANY('{a,steeple,the}'::TEXT[]) to make explicit array conversion
```

Comment: The regexp_split_to_array() function might be of use here, depending on the source of your lookup words.  Or maybe a JOIN to the results of regexp_split_to_table().  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER

Answer (score 2):

If you are not sure about the value and even not sure whether the field will be an empty string or even null then,

```
.where("column_1 ILIKE ANY(ARRAY['','%abc%','%xyz%']) OR column_1 IS NULL")
```

Above query will cover all possibility.